# How do I make this Python renaming code faster?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a code for renaming files (several different formats) all of the type 000_PROTEINNAME_.... The goal is to replace the protein name with its respective gene name.

I have saved these two values in a dictionary with protein name as key and gene name as value (the names themselves are extracted into lists by two columns of a tsv file containing this information, I then use the lists to make the dictionary).
I'm currently running this and although it works, the folders contain up to 4000 files and it is taking too long to run. Do you have any suggestions on how I can decrease running time on this one?

```
def RenameAlphaFold(files_path, reference_table_path):
    with open(reference_table_path) as names:
        TSV_table = csv.reader(names, delimiter= '\t')
        original_names = []
        new_names = []
        for line in TSV_table:
            original_names.append(line[2])
            new_names.append(line[5])
    names = dict(zip(original_names, new_names))
    for old, new in names.items():
        for file in os.listdir(files_path):
            destination = file.replace(old, new)
            source = files_path + '\\' + file
            destination = files_path + '\\' + destination
            os.rename(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I *think* you are running `os.rename` too many times

It seems you are running this for *every* file in `files_path`, regardless of whether it needs to be renamed, *for every replacement combination*.

#### Quick fix

Change this

```
        os.rename(source, destination)
```

to this

```
        if source != destination:
            os.rename(source, destination)
```

#### Potentially more elegant fix

I don't quite know if this would work, but if it does, it will be elegant.

Loop first over the files, then do the replacement of the *strings* but only do one renaming per file.

```py
    for file in os.listdir(files_path):
        source = files_path + '\\' + file
        destination = files_path + '\\' + file
        
        for old, new in names.items():
            destination = destination.replace(old, new)
        
        if source != destination:
            os.rename(source, destination)
```

#### Substring problems?

```
    with open(reference_table_path) as names:
        TSV_table = csv.reader(names, delimiter= '\t')
        name_pairs = []
        for line in TSV_table:
            name_pairs.append(line[2],line[5])

    name_pairs = sorted(name_pairs,
        key = -len(name_pairs[0])
    )
     

    for source in os.listdir(files_path):
       destination = source
       for name_pair in name_pairs:
            destination = destination.replace(old, new)

       if source != destination:
            os.rename(
                files_path + '\\' + source, 
                files_path + '\\' + destination
            )
```

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your answer a lot, I am trying the code now. I may ask an additional question if possible: is there a way I can make the string search more specific? For example, the protein name 'VGLI' was changed to 'VUL115I' because 'GL' is recognised as a substring. However, VGLI should have been changed to UL37. Is there any way I can check this?

Comment: Try sorting them by length of the old name. This way the _longer_ old names are replaced first.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 loops, one over a dictionary, the other one over a folder. Currently, you iterate once the dictionary, but iterate many times over the folder (once per row in your tsv file) while disk accesses are known to be much slower that memory accesses. You should at least invert your loops:

```
for file in os.listdir(files_path):
    for old, new in names.items():
        ...
```

Another (less important IMHO) possible improvement would be to access the dictionary per keys if you can easily extract the protein name from the file name, i.e. if they have a simple and common pattern. If it does not make sense, do not bother building a dictionnary, and directly build a list of pairs:

```
with open(reference_table_path) as names:
    TSV_table = csv.reader(names, delimiter= '\t')
    names = [(line[2], line[5]) for line in TSV_table
for file in os.listdir(files_path):
    for old, new in names:
        ...
```

At least, this is simpler than your original code, so easier to type and maintain...

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. I will try this right now. I may ask an additional question if possible: is there a way I can make the string search more specific? For example, the protein name 'VGLI' was changed to 'VUL115I' because 'GL' is recognised as a substring. However, VGLI should have been changed to UL37. Is there any way I can check this?